# Calculator built using AngularJS not showing result

Tags: angularjs, html

In AngularJs Tutorial I have built a simple Calculator but when I click on calculate button it does not show the output. I am not sure where I am doing the mistake. The HTML file has three text input fields and five buttons. When I click on calculate button the output doesn't appear

My HTML file code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="calc">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div align="center" data-ng-controller="CalcCtrl as c1">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="c1.num1"></input>
            <span data-ng-bind="c1.selectedOperation"></span>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="c1.num2"></input>
            <span></span>
            <input type="text">{{c1.result}}</input>
        <p>
             <button data-ng-click="c1.buttonClicked('+')">+</button>
            <button data-ng-click="c1.buttonClicked('-')">-</button>
             <button data-ng-click="c1.buttonClicked('*')">*</button>
             <button data-ng-click="c1.buttonClicked('/')">/</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button data-ng-click="c1.calcResult()">calculate</button>
        </p>
        {{c1.num1}} {{c1.num2}}
    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

My App.JS file

```
var app = angular.module("calc", []);
app.controller('CalcCtrl', calc);

function calc() {
    this.result = 0;
    this.buttonClicked = function(button){
        this.selectedOperation=button;
    }
    this.calcResult=function(){
        var1 n1=parseFloat(this.num1);
        var2 n2=parseFloat(this.num2);

        if(this.selectedOperation==='+') {
            this.result = n1+n2;
        }else if(this.selectedOperation==='-') {
            this.result = n1-n2;
        }else if(this.selectedOperation==='*') {
            this.result = n1*n2;
        }else if(this.selectedOperation==='\') {
                 this.result = n1/n2;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what are the changes I did from your code, because I have changed more code and added some features. You can just copy paste this below snippet.

### Working Snippet

```js
angular.module("calc",[]).controller('CalcCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.result = 0;
    $scope.buttonClicked = function(button){
        this.selectedOperation=button;
    };
    $scope.calcResult = function(){
        var n1 = parseFloat($scope.num1);
        var n2 = parseFloat($scope.num2);
        if($scope.selectedOperation==='+') {
            $scope.result = n1+n2;
        }else if($scope.selectedOperation==='-') {
            $scope.result = n1-n2;
        }else if($scope.selectedOperation==='*') {
            $scope.result = n1*n2;
        }else if($scope.selectedOperation==='/') {
                 $scope.result = n1/n2;
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="calc" align="center" ng-controller="CalcCtrl">
            <input type="text" ng-change="calcResult()" ng-model="num1"></input>
            <span ng-bind="selectedOperation"></span>
            <input type="text" ng-change="calcResult()" ng-model="num2"></input>
            <span></span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="result"></input>
        <p>
             <button ng-click="buttonClicked('+');calcResult()">+</button>
            <button ng-click="buttonClicked('-');calcResult()">-</button>
             <button ng-click="buttonClicked('*');calcResult()">*</button>
             <button ng-click="buttonClicked('/');calcResult()">/</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button ng-click="calcResult()">calculate</button>
        </p>
        {{num1}}{{selectedOperation}} {{num2}} = {{result}}
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I figured out what mistake I was making. Now it is working. :)

Comment: @bhaskardas Then don't forget to mark as this an answer. Thanks. Also I have added some extra features, like I have calling the calculation function while you change the input value and operations.

Answer (score 1):

`else if(this.selectedOperation==='\')` must be `else if(this.selectedOperation==='/')`. You are escaping the second quotation mark.

Comment: Yes, I changed this one. But I had made another mistake which I figured out. I have corrected the code and now it is working. Thanks for figuring out the mistake in my code. :)

Answer (score 1):

At first the input tag is a standalone tag and has no value inside. Try to use data-ng-model instead or set the value to a span.

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="c1.result" />
```

or

```
<span>{{c1.result}}</span>
```

Then have a look at the browser console if there are any errors reported.

Comment: Yes I changed it to use <span></span> tag now. It doesn't work when I use the <input type="text" data-ng-bind="c1.result"></input>. I figured out another mistake which I had done. Now it's working. Thanks for figuring out the mistake.